# What is happening in this C code? (From interview)

Tags: c

I was given a variation of this C code in an interview recently, and asked what would be returned by the function.

```
#define fun(a) a*a

int main() {    
  return(fun(4+5));   
}
```

I've run it with a `printf("%d"...)` in place of the return and it prints 29. No other types than "%d" showed a result. Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: Textbook case of why you need to use parenthesis in macro expansions

Comment: @bta true, but even with parenthesis, you cannot handle all cases. `fun(i++)` for instance.

Comment: I'm sure there are at least 10 dupes of this.

Comment: I'd say textbook case of why you shouldn't abuse macros.

Comment: macros are easily abused by using the same parameter more than once. About the duplicate: the information is somewhere on SO, but maybe not asked in the same "job interview" angle.

Comment: So what was your answer in the interview?

Answer (score 11):

`a` is expanded, not evaluated as `a`. So you get:

```
4+5*4+5
```

and with operator priorities; you get `4 + 20 + 5 => 29`

better way (with extra outside parenthesis for protecting against outside operators too thanks to Thomas comment):

```
#define fun(a) ((a)*(a))
```

but all parenthesis of the world still don't protect against `i++`, function calls (with side effects, preferably)... so argument reusing in macros is always a problem (there's no syntax to declare & assign a temp variable either). Prefer inlined functions in that case.

Comment: `(((((((a)*(a)))))))` ... Sorry, but my inner troll just had too when you said the extra ones won't hurt :P

Comment: @StoryTeller I thought of that too :) and my last edit is just an echo to your comment (that I just read). Better safe than sorry.

Comment: You need one pair of outer parentheses, for cases such as `100/fun(4*5)`. More than that _can_ hurt, yes...

Comment: you mean "hurt the eyes", right?

Comment: I guess with enough extra parentheses you can hit some limitation in the compiler. I don't remember if the standard has a minimum size of a source file that a conforming implementation has to be able to handle. But yes, mostly "hurt the eyes".